# How to edit/format table output in aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is my command which I run from my AWS CLI

aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceType,Tags[].[Key]]" --region us-east-1 --output table > filename.txt

My output I get is

---

|        DescribeInstances        |

t2.small
Contact
Environment
Asset
Product
Role
Application
Name
Organisation
m4.large
Application
Name
Organisation
Contact
Role
Product
Asset
Environment
m4.large
Environment
Application
Organisation
Name
Product
Asset
Contact
Role

But, what I want is

Contact...............t2.small
Environment.......t2.small
Asset..................t2.small

How Can I get this format in the output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

What you can do, is output as JSON and then process it through `jq` to convert it into whatever format you wish.

See: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

> **jq** is like `sed` for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data with the same ease that `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and friends let you play with text.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this using a little tweaking of the square brackets in the query syntax. Essentially, wrap all of the query fields in a square bracket and add an array style open/close square bracket to the end before closing the outer bracket.

Please change the inline BASH variables shown in the example below with your specific values.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id ${INSTANCE_ID} --output table --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,KeyName,PrivateIpAddress,SubnetId,SecurityGroups[].GroupId][]]' --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
```